# how to know all INSERT SUCCESS in mysqli_multi_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

i have code, and that code generate this syntax:

```
$sql = "INSERT.....,; INSERT......,; INSERT.....,; INSERT......;";
if(mysqli_multi_query($connection,$sql)){
    echo "SUCCESS!";
}else{
    echo "FAILED!";
}
```

how to know ALL INSERT IS SUCCESS from mysqli_multi_query()?,

> mysqli_multi_query return a bool (true or false), but if i have many INSERT  in that function and Only 1 entered from some INSERT, that function is return TRUE.

I want to make sure all the commands **run perfectly**.

Comment: Either combine the queries into one INSERT statement if they all insert into the same table or separate them into separate calls so you can check the status of them individually.

Comment: I think you mean is create many "mysqli_query()" to INSERT many table true @JohnConde? if true, Whether this will make a lot of resources? (i just asking to you :) )

Comment: Are these all the same query or different `INSERT`s?

Comment: i have different tables each insert.. @Machavity

Comment: how about starting a transaction then if one query fail roll back the entire transaction? and use try..catch

Comment: @AbdulAzizAlBasyir There's not that much of a performance hit in running `mysqli_query` multiple times. In fact, I'd say you're less safe with `mysqli_multi_query` since it opens you up to a larger set of SQL injection attacks

Comment: @Machavity if i use many **mysqli_query()**, whether this will make many resources?

Comment: @AbdulAzizAlBasyir Assuming you mean connections to MySQL, the answer is No. If you mean PHP resources, not really. There's a technical hit for calling multiple functions, but unless we're talking thousands of queries, the hit will be negligible

Comment: why dont you make separate calls and then check if they were successful individually?

Comment: If I make it separately, example First insert is success, and second insert failed because many resource in my hosting (example problem connection to mysql, etc) ,If anyone there is another way to make sure everything goes into the database, if any fails, then the system will not check into the database repeatedly any queries that have been entered earlier in order to lighten the server load, I want everything into the database / fail all to the database

Comment: Don't think this is the correct duplicate for this question

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile, if true why i have tag duplicate question from someone..?